# C# LiveCharts ColumnSeries doesnt appear

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, livecharts

I'm trying to make a chart using DateTimePoints and int values in a WinForm app, but when getting the data from the database, and returning it in a ChartValues variable the columns doesnt appear (lineseries works great).

This is the code which contains the query for the database:

```
public List<Tuple<DateTime, int>> FetchDataFromDatabase()
{
    List<Tuple<DateTime, int>> rawData = new List<Tuple<DateTime, int>>();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT date, SUM(ossz+selejt) as Teszt FROM OEE_DB GROUP BY date", connection))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DateTime date = reader.GetDateTime(0);
                int value = reader.GetInt32(1);
                rawData.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, int>(date, value));
            }
        }
    }

    return rawData;
}
```

And this is how i assign them to a chartvalues variable:

```
private ChartValues<DateTimePoint> GetChartData()
{
    data nd = new data();
    ChartValues<DateTimePoint> chartData = new ChartValues<DateTimePoint>();

    List<Tuple<DateTime, int>> rawData = nd.FetchDataFromDatabase();

    foreach (var dataPoint in rawData)
    {
        DateTime date = dataPoint.Item1;
        double value = dataPoint.Item2;

        DateTimePoint point = new DateTimePoint(date, value);
        chartData.Add(point);
    }

    return chartData;
}
```

Finally, this is how i make the chart, and how it appears:

```
monthCalendar1.Enabled = false;
monthCalendar1.Visible = false;
label4.Visible = false;
numericUpDown1.Visible = false;
cartesianChart1.Series.Clear();
cartesianChart1.AxisX.Clear();
cartesianChart1.AxisY.Clear();
cartesianChart1.Zoom = ZoomingOptions.Xy;
cartesianChart1.Series.Add(new ColumnSeries
{
    Title = "OEE",
    Values = GetChartData(),
    Fill = gradientBrush,
    StrokeThickness = 100,
    MaxColumnWidth = 50,
    PointGeometry = DefaultGeometries.Circle,
    DataLabels = true,
});
var xAxis1 = new Axis
{
    LabelFormatter = val => new System.DateTime((long)val).ToString("yyyy. MM. dd"),
};

cartesianChart1.AxisX.Add(xAxis1);

cartesianChart1.AxisY.Add(new Axis
{
    LabelFormatter = val => val.ToString("F0") + "%"
});

SetXAxisLimits(DateTime.Now);
```

[image: LiveCharts ColumnSeries]

I tried setting the max width manually as seen in the code, but nothing seems to work when using DateTimePoints for the X values, but when using anything else it works (I need to use DateTimePoints as X axis)